# Confusion with Soft asserting if a message is present

Tags: java, webdriver, assert

I am automating a form, the scenario is, when an invalid entry is given, the message 'Success' shouldn't appear

I tried to check this using

```
s_assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Succes')]")).isDisplayed(), false);
```

But, while running, it shows 'Unable to locate element:'

The message appears only if my test fails. So expected behavior is that, the element won't be present.

How to tell `webdriver` to just check if it is present and to not to throw an error! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is not related to *Assertion* rather find element mechanism. You are expecting an element that was not located by the `Selenium` and thus code has not reached till the *Assertion*

You have to do some kind of exception handling depending on what you want. before assert.

```
public bool Test()
{
    try
    {

        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("test"));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { // catch the exception you want
        return false;
    }
}

public void TestAssert()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(Test(),false);
}
```

**Note: mine is C# and NUnit**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I just want to check if an element is present. Any way other than using findElement?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... I added the below code which fixed my problem.

```
     public static boolean isElementPresent(String xpath) {
          try {
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
           return true;
          } catch (Exception e) {
           return false;
          }
         }

     public void formsNegetive() {
```

boolean b = isElementPresent(("//div[@class='alert-box success']"));
                            if (b) {
                            s_assert.assertEquals("Success: You will be contacted by our experts soon.", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.alert-box.success")).getText());
                            }
      }